# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception

Tags: java

I got `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"` exception while running following code snippet. I have set JVM heap size `8192M` with command `set JVM_ARGS="-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m"`.

```
    List<Integer> largeList = new ArrayList<>();

    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE/2;i++)
    {
        largeList.add(rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }
```

I think JVM heapsize, I set, is big enough to hold array.

Comment: Not the solution, but you are using -Xms twice (badly copied/pasted?) and you probably want an -Xmx in there too.

Comment: You're trying to add more than 1 billion elements to a list. Are you sure 8GB is enough?

Comment: Thanks @SurfMan for pointing out, but still not working as per others' answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `List` can only hold objects.

An `Integer` object needs at least 4 byte for the actual value and some amount of bytes for various object-related overhead (varies by JVM, but is usually around 16-30 bytes per object).

`Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2` is about a billion. So for the data alone (without object overhead) you'd need 4 billion bytes to store the list. That's 4GB. So even if the object overhead was only 4 bytes (very hard to do, and probably not very efficient at runtime), that would already use up all 8GB of your heap (and leave nothing for all of the classes needed to run your code). And that doesn't even include the memory held for the `ArrayList` which needs to hold that many references (which are either 8 or 4 bytes, depending on what JVM and which settings you use).

So no, you've not assigned it nearly enough memory.

*If* you actually need that many `int` values, consider using a `int[]` which is significantly more memory efficient than that, effectively taking 4 bytes per `int` with a small fixed-sized overhead.

Comment: Using int[] worked (needed to set JVM args through eclipse)!!

Answer (score 4):

When the ArrayList is full, its size is increased by 50% - so the size of your list may be as high as 0.75 * MAX_VALUE = 0.75 * 2^31  = 1.6 billion.

An Integer takes 16 bytes in memory, and each Integer reference takes 4 or 8 bytes in the list. Lets assume 4 here. So your list could take up to 1 billion * 16 + 0.6 billion * 4 (for null entries) = 30 GB in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a `int` is 4 bytes, so in theory you'll have more than 4 GB of `Integer`s in your heap due to the wrapper's overhead; another point is that `ArrayList` changes its size by using `Arrays.copyOf()`, so more memory is needed to resize the list itself to ensure its capacity is enough while filling.

Comment: An Integer uses more than 4 bytes due to the class overhead.